# Deploying a solution, IIS and Web Service

Tags: web-services, deployment, web

Basic question:

When you deploy a solution with Visual Studio 2010, where the views is placed?

I've opened my IIS and I try to found the files deployed and I doesn't find it.

Another issue is concerned to find a webservice that was deployed together the solution. Where it is physically deployed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually youll find the webservices deployed if done correctly to this physical folder:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI

like i said its how you have done the webservice (wsdl and disco build) putting the files within the above. Or by creating a new application within iis to host your custom list of webservices, obviously the first approach is best and correct.

views on the other hand are stored on sharepoint i would presume within a list which in turn is stored witin the sql database that has a cell connecting the list with its given views.. you shouldnt go into the database and fiddle about but rather use webservices:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd586201.aspx

or sharepoint designer:

open spd -> navigate to list -> you should see a list of views assosicated with it -> add / edit / delete.